# Loading .CSV file into ORACLES SQL Developer through CMD line

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I have a current problem loading my .CSV file into Oracles SQL Database

I am using SQLLDR

I have an excel file that has a lot of stock information in it I will give you a sample of what it looks like

```
       Tdate       Symbol    Open     High    Low     Close      Volume   
       19500103     SPX      16.66    16.66   16.66   16.66     1260000
       19500104     SPX      16.85    16.85   16.85   16.85     1890000
       19500105     SPX      16.93    16.93   16.93   16.93     2550000
```

Tdate , symbol , open , high , low , close and volume isnt in the .CSV file I just put it there because my database table will hold those values under those names.

I created my Table in Sql Developer

```
create table cts ( tdate date, symbol varchar(20), open numeric ( 18,8), high numeric (18,8), low ( numeric 18,8), close numeric (18,8) , volume int ) ;
```

So then I opened up a notepad file and created this

```
LOAD Data infile c:\cts.dump.csv
```

into table CTS

```
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
( tdate, symbol, open, high, low , close, volume)
```

I save it as loaderval.ctl in folder c:\data

I then proceed to open up my cmd window and type

```
sqlldr username/password control=c:\data\loaderval.ctl
```

I receive back that 64 lines have been committed which is impossible since the file has tons and tons of data. I then check my database and the table is empty.
I also receive a .bad file and the .bad file has the records from the first couple of rows of the excel sheet

```
( 19500103,SPX,16.66,16.66,16.66,16.66,1260000
19500104,SPX,16.85,16.85,16.85,16.85,1890000
19500105,SPX,16.93,16.93,16.93,16.93,2550000
19500106,SPX,16.98,16.98,16.98,16.98,2010000
19500109,SPX,17.08,17.08,17.08,17.08,2520000
19500110,SPX,17.03,17.03,17.03,17.03,2160000
19500111,SPX,17.09,17.09,17.09,17.09,2630000
19500112,SPX,16.76,16.76,16.76,16.76,2970000
19500113,SPX,16.67,16.67,16.67,16.67,3330000
19500116,SPX,16.72,16.72,16.72,16.72,1460000
19500117,SPX,16.86,16.86,16.86,16.86,1790000
19500118,SPX,16.85,16.85,16.85,16.85,1570000
19500119,SPX,16.87,16.87,16.87,16.87,1170000
19500120,SPX,16.90,16.90,16.90,16.90,1440000
19500123,SPX,16.92,16.92,16.92,16.92,1340000
19500124,SPX,16.86,16.86,16.86,16.86,1250000
19500125,SPX,16.74,16.74,16.74,16.74,1700000
19500126,SPX,16.73,16.73,16.73,16.73,1150000
19500127,SPX,16.82,16.82,16.82,16.82,1250000
19500130,SPX,17.02,17.02,17.02,17.02,1640000
19500131,SPX,17.05,17.05,17.05,17.05,1690000
19500201)
```

Please help :)

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using SQLLDR !

Comment: Hi @linyu21, You could edit question details, to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at code it seems that date column may be the culprit here. You can check below link to how to handle dates for sql loader

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/sql-loader-enhancements-12cr1

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE c:\cts.dump.csv
INTO TABLE CTS
FIELDS CSV WITH EMBEDDED
   (tdate    DATE "YYYYDDMM" ":tdate",
    symbol,
    open,
    high,
    low,
    close,
    volumn)

$ sqlldr userid=userid/passwd@connect_string control=test.ctl
```

Comment: i see that the format has to be DD-MON-YYYY ? how would i change that in my code? do i have to create a new table with a specific format for the date?

Comment: You need not create a new table. You need to alter you control file. I will give the syntax once I m little free.

Comment: also confirm date format, I have taken it based on sample values provided by you.